# Print (multi)dimensional array in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Is there an easy way to print an array, which is potentially multi-dimensional, to the Console in VB.NET for the purpose of debugging (i.e. just checking that the contents of the array is correct).

Coming from an Objective-C background the `NSLog` function prints a reasonably well formatted output, such as the following for a one-dimensional array:

```
myArray {
    0 => "Hello"
    1 => "World"
    2 => "Good Day"
    3 => "To You!"
}
```

and similar for a multi-dimensional array (the following is an example of a two-dimensional array output):

```
myTwoDArray {
    0 => {
        0 => "Element"
        1 => "Zero"
    }
    1 => {
        0 => "Element"
        1 => "One"
    }
    2 => {
        0 => "Element"
        1 => "Two"
    }
    3 => {
        0 => "Element"
        1 => "Three"
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Question! It would be a great option!

Comment: Microsoft decided that this functionality wasn’t important enough to be included in the .NET framework. No idea what they were smoking.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any native (in-built) function to do that, 
Yet the function below should work fine.

```
Public Shared Sub PrintValues(myArr As Array)
  Dim s As String = ""
  Dim myEnumerator As System.Collections.IEnumerator = myArr.GetEnumerator()
  Dim i As Integer = 0
  Dim cols As Integer = myArr.GetLength(myArr.Rank - 1)
  While myEnumerator.MoveNext()
    If i < cols Then
      i += 1
    Else
      'Console.WriteLine()
      s = s & vbCrLf
      i = 1
    End If
    'Console.Write(ControlChars.Tab + "{0}", myEnumerator.Current)
    s = s & myEnumerator.Current & " "
  End While
  'Console.WriteLine()
  MsgBox(s)
End Sub
```

For the sake of testing the function out in a non console application, I have added the string variable S, which you should be able to omit when you use the function in a console application.