# displaying a 2d array as rows and columns in visual basic console

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm trying to display the below 2d array as rows and columns.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        'declaring and initializing a 2d array 
        Dim a1(,) As Integer = {{2, 3}, {5, 3}}

        For Each ele As Integer In a1

            Console.WriteLine(ele)


        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

i need the output to be like:

```
2 5
3 3
```

I need your help guys. please

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403361/print-multidimensional-array-in-visual-basic ?

Answer (score 3):

Just loop thru each dimension separately:

```
For I as Integer = 0 to a1.GetUpperBound(0)
   For J as Integer = 0 to a1.GetUpperBound(1)
      Console.Write("{0} ", a1(j,i))
   Next
   console.WriteLine()
Next
```

**Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8K7fkp**